# How to run .sml file by using emacs?

Tags: emacs, smlnj

I'm not able to run simple .sml file in emacs. Please, help me.

Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Sun Jul 14 09:59:19 2013]
- use "s.sml" ;

[opening s.sml]
[use failed: Io: openIn failed on "s.sml", Win32TextPrimIO:openRd: failed]

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/interact.sml:24.14-24.28

Thanks,
Darshan

Comment: Say what you've done to get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following

```
1.Close Emacs,then open it
2.Create new file by C-x C-f
3.enter valid sml code in the file wc you created and named test.sml say
4.C-x C-s to save it 
5.M-x run-sml and press return twice
6.In the sml REPL enter use "test.sml";press return 
7.This is it!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory before you run sml is the same one as the one where the file exists. Otherwise, you must use the file's absolute path. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148737/opening-sml-file-use-fail) question which deals with the same problem (and suggests it might be an issue with file not being specified correctly).